# Injecting HttpContext in Ninject 2

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, httpcontext

In my asp.net mvc application I'm using Ninject as a DI framework.

My HttpAccountService is used by my controllers to get info from and to cookies.
For this I need the HttpContext.Current in the HttpAccountService.
As this is a dependency I injected it throught the constructor as such:

```
kernel.Bind<IAccountService>()
    .To<HttpAccountService>()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", HttpContext.Current);
```

Sadly this always binds to the same context which makes that after the first request finishes this context becomes outdated.

How should I correctly inject my HttpContext?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`WithConstructorArgument` has an overload that takes a `Func<NinjectContext,T>`, i.e., you can use:

> **...** `.WithConstructorArgument("context",`**ninjectContext=>**`HttpContext.Current);`

which will call the provided 'callback' lambda within the request processing and obtain the correct value at that point in time [as opposed to you calling the other overload and supplying a constant value which gets computed at `Bind<>` time].

(If you're not trying to Mock the context, I assume you'll consider using it inline)

Comment: That syntax doesn't seem to compile. It compiles with x=>HttpContext.Current, but this doesn't achieve the expected result.
Could it be because I get my ninjectkernel from a (static) factory?

Comment: On further inspection it seems I now DO get the correct context, but my problem must lie somehwere else. Thx

Comment: for the record: it was because a RedirectToRoute resets that requests cookies.

Comment: @Ruben - Is this how I would inject the current user into my Kernal? i.e. Http.Context.User, I want this user injected into my domain service however I am finding it difficult... After the user loggs on I would want to inject him and access him in my service layer that does not reference the web, would this be possible?

Comment: @Haroon: While it's possible, it may not always be a good idea. Stuff like the current user should not generally be come into play (though you can do it by using `Ninject.Parameters.Parameter` with `shouldInherit` set to `true` and then in your `Bind`ing picking up the value. A far better general approach is to have your components depend on an e.g. `IUserContext` and have that manage the retrieval of relevant information. Typically you wouldnt use any `System.Web` stuff in your services layer directly. I recommend reading @Mark Seemann's top answers around here and the haze will lift quickly!

Comment: @Ruben: thanks for your reply, I dont understand where I actually do the binding for this or how, I did have a read through some of Marks answers that helped a bit, is it possible to see my gist and comment? you can find it @ https://gist.github.com/1042173

Comment: @Ruben: Totally ignore what I said, I managed to get it to work! :P It feels like one of those moments where something has clicked lol... Anyway, is this binding ok:             Container.Bind<IUserSession>().To<UserSession>().InRequestScope(); I am updating my gist, if you could comment that would be wonderful!