# How can I automatically set certain entity properties. using EF Code First whenever an entity is saved to the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

There are certain cases for values that should always be updated when an object is persisted to the database. I can find no entry point for doing this other than overriding `DbContext.ValidateEntity` and modifying the `CurrentValues` property collection, but in my opinion using a validation method to modify object properties carries a very bad smell. Is there any other means of doing this?

Comment: You are right about validation - overriding validation to change property values may be dangerous (one of the reason is that detect changes is not called after validation has completed). What you can do however is to override SaveChanges and modify entities and then call base.SaveChanges to follow the regular workflow.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby/7642041#7642041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Eranga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60108/eranga)'s comment above, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby/7642041#7642041) is a perfect fit for my question.

It describes how to override `SaveChanges` on my dbcontext and set the properties I would like to there.