# How can I auto-update the int ModifiedBy property on a Entity with UserId in Entity Framework 4 when saving?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am using Simple Membership and a UserProfile table that maintains UserId and UserName:

```
 public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.webpages_Roles = new List<webpages_Roles>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

With Entity Framework I am running the following which is inside my Context:

```
 public partial class UowContext : DbContext

    // code to set up DbSets here ...
    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    private void ApplyRules()
    {
        var r1 = new Random();
        var r2 = new Random();

        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                     .Where(
                          e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                         (e.State == EntityState.Added) ||
                         (e.State == EntityState.Modified)))
        {
            IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                e.CreatedBy = // I want to put the integer value of UserId here
                e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            e.ModifiedBy = // I want to put the integer value of UserId here
            e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Here is the schema showing how user information is stored. Note that I store the integer UserId and not the UserName in the tables:

```
public abstract class AuditableTable : IAuditableTable
{
    public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an example of a controller action that I use:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostContent(Content content)
    {
        try
        {
            _uow.Contents.Add(content);
            _uow.Commit();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Content>(HttpStatusCode.Created, content);
            return response;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ex);
        } 
    }
```

I then have:

```
public class UowBase : IUow, IDisposable
{
    public UowBase(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbContext();

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    public IRepository<Content> Contents { get { return GetStandardRepo<Content>(); } }
```

and:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("An instance of DbContext is required to use this repository", "context");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

How can I determine the UserId from inside of my Context so I can populate the Id in my tables?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby/7642041#7642041

Comment: Thanks for the link but that question populates ModifiedBy with name and my database stores the UserId. I will update my question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Do you mena DbContext? Where are you creating and using the Context? In a Controller Action? How does the invoking code look like?

Comment: Yes the code above is inside:  public partial class UowContext : DbContext

Comment: Your `UowContext` should have a property 'UserId' and it should be populated in your controller(idealy through DI).

Answer (score 0):

In Code you will have UserName with you through:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

you can than query `UserProfile` table against that Name and get the UserId from there and than assign it to ModifiedBy attribute.

Make sure that you query UserProfile table outside the foreach loop :)