# ASP MVC best practice for getting current username in UnitOfWork data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP MVC best practice for getting current username in UnitOfWork data access layer?

I can not retrieve the authenticated user in UI APP in UnitOfWork class, please invaluable assistance

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditoria>();

    if (changeSet != null)
    {
        string username = "Dafault";
        DateTime dateAudit = DateTime.UtcNow;
        foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
        {
            if (entry.State.Equals(EntityState.Added))
            {
                entry.Entity.UsuarioCreacion = username;
                entry.Entity.FechaCreacion = dateAudit;
            }
            entry.Entity.GuidAuditoria = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            entry.Entity.FechaActualizacion = dateAudit;
            entry.Entity.UsuarioActualizacion = username;//"HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name"
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: pass it as a parameter from your controller's scope

Comment: Take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby