# Overriding SaveChanges to Save ModifiedBy and ModifiedOn using MVC Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, httpcontext, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to save a record and apply the CreatedBy/ModifiedBy GUID (Id) as well as the CreatedOn / ModifiedOn fields from my base dbContext class.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby) article that looks like what I want to accomplish, but in MVC Core 1.0 you do not have access to **System.Web** to get to **HttpContext**.

Another good article that shows what I want to do is [this](http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/)

The code sample I am refering to is this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>();
    if (changeSet != null)
    {
        foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
        {
            entry.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateProvider.GetCurrentDate();
            entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a way to get the HttpContext otherwise in Core Framework?

Comment: you can use dependency injection to inject IHttpContextAccessor into DbContext

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current` does not exist anymore. You can access it via the `IHttpContextAccessor` in the following way:

In `Startup.cs`, add: `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Then:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor_;

public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    httpContextAccessor_ = httpContextAccessor;
    var username = httpContextAccessor_.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Also note that IHttpContextAccessor will be only available in classes, which are 
resolved/created by the DI container.