# Entity Framework 6 - Always update properties that were manually setted by code - Change behavior of change tracker in proxy classes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, proxy-classes

This is Entity Framework 6.1.3 with .NET v4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

In my, DB I have hundreds of tables with column `LastChangedByUser` in which I store the login of the user who last updated the row.

Unfortually, I have legacy triggers `FOR UPDATE` on almost all tables, and they all verify `IF UPDATE(LastChangedByUser)` and raise an error if this column is not included in the `SET` clause of the updated. I suppose the original developers did this to make sure the developers included every required column in their manually-written update queries.

By default EF only includes the properties that had their values changed when generating the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` query. And this is causing problems in the following scenario: If previously some row was last changed by "user1", and the same "user1" tries to updates this row again later, EF is not including the `LastChangedByUser` column in it's generated `SET` clause, since it was set to the same value that it previously had. And the trigger is raising the error.

My legacy system (pre-EF) includes the `LastChangedByUser` in the `SET` clause in manually-written queries, regardless of the value being unaltered, so the trigger validations do OK for those old queries.

So I need to "mimic" this behavior in Entity Framework: if the code explicitly set a property value of a bound Entity proxy, I need its corresponding `DbPropertyEntry` to have the `IsModified` set to `true` regardless of the value being the same as the previous value.

I don't want to include all the columns in the `SET` cause (I tried this and had other trigger problems). I just want to include the columns that were set explicitly, like:

```
//this should make the property IsModified become true
//even if it was already "user1" when the entity loaded
myEntity.LastChangedByUser = "user1";
```

If the code simply dos not change the property (the setter is never called), then the property should remain with `IsModified == false`.

Is it possible to solve this? Maybe this default behaviour is too intrinsic and can't be changed...

Unfortunately I cannot just disable/drop the triggers, since they do tons of business rules on which the legacy system is dependent. And they are hundreds, so editing each one of them will be really tough...

Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to override SaveChanges() to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641552/overriding-savechanges-and-setting-modifieddate-but-how-do-i-set-modifiedby

Comment: I tried it, the problem is that the harm seems be done at this point. There is no way to detect if the property was set or not. What I need to do is somehow intercept the setter of the proxy class, but I don't know how to acheive that... that is if it would be possible at all